# dismissViewControllerAnimated doesn't dismiss

Tags: ios, user-interface

I am working on an iPad app that has a login controller which segues into a view controller. The login controller is declared thusly:

```
@interface LoginController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>
```

and the storyboard has (as expected), a username and password text field and a button for authentication and logging into the main app. The button calls the shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier(...) function and the view switches from the login view to the main view.

I would like to also mimic this programmatically, when the user hits return on the password text box. I've trapped the event, but I can't seem to get the switchover to happen. The code I'm using is:

```
    if (theTextField == self.password)
{
    BOOL loginSuccessful = [self shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:@"switchToViewer" sender:self];

    if (loginSuccessful == YES)
    {
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
            NSLog(@"I should be dismissing here!\n");
        }];
    }
}
```

However, the view never gets dismissed. I should note that this is on iOS 7, I don't know if that matters. Any ideas?

EDIT: My workaround for now is to spoof the button touch event:

```
[self.signIn sendActionsForControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Hacky, but it works :)

Answer (score 4):

```
[self.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: Check your presentingViewController property an make sure it's not nil.  It sounds like something else is wrong.  Also, modal views should not dismiss themselves.  I wish I could provide a reference, but I saw a note about it in some Apple documentation years ago.

Comment: here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ModalViewControllers/ModalViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH111-SW1